# Surjectivity of $\mathcal{id}_{\mathbb{R}^n}+g$ when $g$ is a contraction?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Assume $g:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a [contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping) and consider $h=\mathcal{id}_{\mathbb{R}^n}+g$. The map $h$ is injective. Is it always surjective?

My question has the [following one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346172/prove-that-xg-is-homeomorphism) for origin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Let $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  We want to find $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $y = h(x) = x + g(x)$.  Consider the function $f(x) = y - g(x)$, which is a contraction since
$$
| f(x) - f(z) | = | g(z) - g(x)|
$$
and $g$ is a contraction.  Then $f$ has a unique fixed point, i.e. there exists a unique $x$ such that $f(x) =x$, which is equivalent to $y = x + g(x) = h(x)$.

Since $y$ was arbitrary we deduce that $h$ is surjective.